# SOQL Query Question

Tags: soql

I want to check the surname matching lastname and Pcode matching MailingPostalCode in the query of SOQL.

```
public class ContactSearch 
{
    public static list<contact> searchForContacts(String Surname,String PCode)
    {   
        list<Contact> Listquery = [select ID, Name, LastName, MailingPostalCode from contact 
                                  where lastName IN : Surname];
    }

}
```

Comment: why do you use `IN` clause? do you have any issues faced with using simple `=` comparison ?

Comment: Yeah I was not adding colon but now added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to extract the records exactly matching the `Surname` and `PCode` simply apply a filter for them.

```
public class ContactSearch 
{
    public static list<contact> searchForContacts(String Surname,String PCode)
    {   
        list<Contact> listQuery = [select ID, Name, LastName, MailingPostalCode from contact 
                                  where lastName =: Surname AND MailingPostalCode=: PCode];

        return listQuery;
    }

}
```

Comment: How to retrieve the result ??

Comment: What you mean? query result will be assigned into `listQuery` you can return in as in my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

To search using wildcard `LIKE` operator use something like

`list<Contact> Listquery = 'SELECT ID, Name, LastName, MailingPostalCode 
 FROM contact 
 WHERE lastName LIKE ' + Surname + '%'
 AND MailingPostalCode =: ' + Pcode`

Or you could use **exact match** `SurName` by just changing one line, as given below, from above query:
`WHERE lastName =:' + Surname`

Comment: Yeah I changed but how we can get the result of list as output ?
Is it the correct way ? 
for(contact c : listquery)
{ system.debug('Answer'+c.get(c.lastname));}

Comment: Yes you can do that or more simply you could use `for(contact c : [SELECT ID ... FROM contact WHERE .... ] )`. using the same query you used to build `ListQuery` variable in `for` loop. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have compare two fields LastName & Surname for matching data right ?

```
List<contact> Listquery = database.query('select ID, Name, LastName, MailingPostalCode from contact where lastName =: Surname');
```

I think you getting error for **IN** operator just remove it and put **=:**

Try This in developer console

```
List<String> surname = new List<String>();
surname.add('Rogers');
List<String> Pcode= new List<String>();
Pcode.add('27215');
List<contact> C =[select ID, Name, LastName, MailingPostalCode from contact where lastName IN : Surname or MailingPostalCode In : PCode];
system.debug(C);
```

Might be this useful for you if i am wrong then correct me.

Comment: I changed that from IN to =: but now I am not getting my listQuery after the following code:
list<Contact> Listquery = [select ID, Name, LastName, MailingPostalCode from contact 
                                  where lastName =: Surname 
                                   AND MailingPostalCode =: PCode];


I am not getting any output after this input

ContactSearch.searchForContacts('Barat', '4y8p9o');

Comment: have you tried your query in developer console??
if not then please check...

Comment: but how should I put a condition of "PCode" and "Surname" in developer console ???

Comment: Its an empty result ! Showing nothing

Comment: use 'Rogers' as surname instead of 'Forbes'.
because if you can see the where clause then according to it the result is empty.
if you are concern about your data into database then adjust where clause accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19571/discussion-between-dksalesforce-lerner-and-sohail-beyondvision).

Comment: Yeah its working now :) Great (Y)